# Adding specific time to display pop up box in exoplayer in android studio

Tags: android-studio, video-processing, exoplayer, duration

I am trying to display some specific time to pop up box in exoplayer using android studio. I am search about these related but these problem is not sort out so these problem related answer sort out.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create and send](http://%20https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html#createMessage-com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlayerMessage.Target-) a [PlayerMessage](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/PlayerMessage.html) at a given playback position and execute arbitrary code at that position:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
long position = 20 * 1000;
player.createMessage(
    (messageType, payload) -> Log.d("TAG", "Hurray! We are at playback position 0:20"))
        .setPosition(position)
        .setHandler(handler)
.send();
```